# C++ QT convert list to one of overloaded functions

Tags: c++, list, qt, overloading

I am looking for a way to convert a list of `QVariant`s into one of overloaded functions that takes either 1, 2, 3 or 4 `QVariant`s.

My initial idea is to just make a `switch` statement on the list's length and call functions based on it, but I am not sure if it is the only solution for this problem, and it doesn't look very scalable:

```
switch(list.length())
{
case 0:
 fun();
case 1:
 fun(list[0]);
 break;
case 2:
 fun(list[0], list[1]);
 break;
case 3:
 fun(list[0], list[1], list[2]);
 break;
...
}
```

Comment: What is the semantics of your `fun`? I guess that the reason it takes 1, 2, 3, or 4 variants is that it interprets each of the arguments in a different way? Otherwise it would just take a collection of variants as an argument?

Comment: It is not this `switch` which is not scalable. It is your `fun` overloads which is not scalable. If you want to make it scalable, consider `fun` which accepts some other kind of arguments, e.g. in a collection. Or make it a variadic template.